# How to make Pod file from one project and add to your own project in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have one complete project. which I downloaded from site.

https://medium.com/learning-xcode-as-a-designer/animate-in-xcode-without-code-20c82a904164

It gave me a project.

I also download a DEMO project which has only added Pods Files, looks below

[image]

After that I made a DemoAnimation project. and made its Pod using pod init, but it made Pod of that project like below

[image]

Now, my confusion is that how to make Pod of canvas project and use into my project. as if I use by dragging and dropping, it doesn't work.

How to make Pod file or existing project and embed into my own project and use it?

Comment: You don't need to open a new project. Open the demo project, Just change the podfile and `pod install`. After dependencies installed, open `xx.xcworkspace`

Comment: I ran pod install, it created PodFile and other xcworkspace in my project, but how can I embed that project into my project?

Comment: If you can download that canvas, and use into your project, then you will know what is my problem exactly dear.

Comment: So if you need to embed this project into your own project, 1. the dependency project has its own cocoapod 2.add a podfile to your project with `pod projectYouNeed` 3.run `pod install` 3.open `yourproject.xcworkspace`

Comment: No podspec found for `Canvas` in `./Canvas.podspec` I got this error while running pod install after pasting podfile into my project

Comment: ahh, `pod 'Canvas', '~> 0.1'`

Comment: pod 'Canvas', '~> 0.1' where and when to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already on CocoaPods,

1.enter to your project root directory.

2.Create a file call `Podfile` and add the content

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Canvas', '~> 0.1'
```

Or open terminal:  (cd to your root directory)

```
$ cd {ROOT_DIR}
$ edit Podfile
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Canvas', '~> 0.1'
```

3.Run `pod install` to install the dependencies.

4.Then you should now have the Xcode workspace (.xcworkspace) ready.

5.Go on with the terminal or just open the `xcworkspace` file.

```
$ open -a xcode App.xcworkspace
```

That's it.